# Recursive query in Oracle until a parent in the hierarchy meets a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, tree, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a table like the following:

```
ID  PARENT_ID  VALUE_ID
1   NULL       100
2   1          NULL
3   2          200
4   3          NULL 
5   1          300
6   2          NULL
7   6          400
8   7          500
```

And I'd like to be able to fetch each ID with its corresponding VALUE_ID. I want to do it in such a way that if a row has a VALUE_ID as NULL, it "inherits" the VALUE_ID of the first parent above it in the hierarchy, that has a VALUE_ID as NOT NULL. So that would be the query result:

```
ID  VALUE_ID
1   100
2   100      // -> inherits the value from PARENT_ID = 1;  
3   200
4   200      // -> inherits the value from PARENT_ID = 3;
5   300
6   100      // -> inherits the value from ID = 1, because the PARENT_ID = 2 also has VALUE_ID as NULL, so it goes deeper in the hierarchy;
7   400    
8   500
```

Could such a thing be accomplished with only one recursive or hierarchical query? Or be accomplished in general without a procedure, perhaps? With CTE, or CONNECT BY clause?

Comment: hoe many level are there for parent child?

Comment: I think the deepest a child is, is 7 levels below the root parent in the real table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with cte(id, value_id, parent_value_id) as (
      select id, value_id, value_id as parent_value_id
      from t
      where value_id is not null
      union all
      select t.id, t.value_id, cte.parent_value_id
      from cte join
           t
           on t.parent_id = cte.id
      where t.value_id is null
     )
select *
from cte
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a564371e5884d5309641fc63aaca9c67) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, just created my account, didn't know only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated hierarchical query and `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` to only return a single row:

```sql
SELECT id,
       parent_id,
       ( SELECT value_id
         FROM   table_name r
         WHERE  connect_by_isleaf = 1
         START WITH r.id = t.id
         CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = id
         AND PRIOR value_id IS NULL
       ) AS value_id
FROM   table_name t
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, PARENT_ID, VALUE_ID ) AS
SELECT 1, NULL, 100  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1,    NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2,    200  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3,    NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1,    300  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 2,    NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 6,    400  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 7,    500  FROM DUAL
```

This outputs:

> ```
> ID | PARENT_ID | VALUE_ID
> -: | --------: | -------:
>  1 |      null |      100
>  2 |         1 |      100
>  3 |         2 |      200
>  4 |         3 |      200
>  5 |         1 |      300
>  6 |         2 |      100
>  7 |         6 |      400
>  8 |         7 |      500
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9c45bbeb5edba67f1c2087b5d7bb7177)*